# Scrollbar appearing in Firefox during CSS animation

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know that a lot of questions have already been asked about the scrollbars in Firefox, but I'm having an issue I can't find answered anywhere else. Basically I have a div that opens/slides right from the left hand side. Within this div are two child divs – a main menu at the top and a social media menu at the bottom. Both of these divs also have css animations applied to them that make them slide inwards/upwards from the outskirts of the parent div, whilst the parent itself is moving.

The position shift on the bottom inner-div is causing the parent div to have a scrollbar on the Y-axis as it moves/opens. I currently have this set to `overflow:auto` which works fine in all browsers but Firefox. Using `overflow:hidden` fixes this, but I can't use that because on my website some of the menu links have submenus, so I need the ability to scroll when these are open.

Here is a fiddle – open in Firefox and click the green button, then the problem will be apparent. Is there a fix / workaround for this?

https://jsfiddle.net/75dtb1zk/15/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="navbar">
        <span id="button-one"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="push-menu">
        <ul class="mobile-menu">
            <li>Link 1</li>
            <li>Link 2</li>
            <li>Link 3</li>
            <li>Link 4</li>
            <li>Link 5</li>
            <li>Link 6</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="social-menu"></div>
    </div>

</header>

<div class="content">


</div>

<footer class="footer">

</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.header .navbar {
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
}
.open-left .header .navbar {
    transform: translate3d(295px, 0, 0);
}
.open-right .header .navbar {
transform: translate3d(-295px, 0, 0);
}
.content {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
.open-left .content {
    transform: translate3d(295px, 0, 0);
}
.open-right .content {
    transform: translate3d(-295px, 0, 0);
}
.footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    background-color: #efefef;
}


#button-one {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.push-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 295px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: wheat;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
    transform: translate3d(-295px, 0px, 0px)
}
.open-left .push-menu {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)
}
ul.mobile-menu {
    position: relative;
    left: -85px;
    width: auto;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
}
.open-left ul.mobile-menu {
    transform: translate3d(85px, 0px, 0px);
}
ul.mobile-menu li {
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
.social-menu {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 150px, 0px);
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(.645, .045, .355, 1);
}
.open-left .social-menu {
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('#button-one').click(function() {
                $('body').toggleClass('open-left');

        });

        $('#button-two').click(function() {
                $('body').toggleClass('open-right');

        });

});
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior in Chrome and FF

Comment: Hm, embarrassing, so am I. Same with my website. I was messing around with inspect element in chrome the other day and I must have changed something to get that result. Do you know if there is a workaround for either browser?

Comment: use `position: fixed` for the `social-menu` would suffice?

Comment: Hi, I did consider it but I like how the flex css pushes it down with the content when the menu exceeds the length of the menu div. This is something else I've been unable to recreate in the jsfiddle for some reason :S

Comment: You could transition the height instead of translating it ... ? : https://jsfiddle.net/75dtb1zk/16/

Comment: Hi, thank you – yes this gets rid of the scrollbar but for some reason it doesn't allow the user to scroll down to the bottom menu when the top menu exceeds the height of the parent div. It effectively cuts it off, it's quite strange. The jsfiddle does this anyway, as I was unable to replicate this from my website.

Comment: Thats cos you have a fixed position set for `push-menu`. For fixed elements, the view-port would be the container. I just saw this. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Hi Ankith, yes I had another look a little earlier on and I managed to do it by adding an outer container to the bottom menu and applying `overflow:hidden` to it, so that it wouldn't increase the height of the main menu div when the menu transitioned up and down. I also gave a `min-height` to the outer container I added so that it wouldn't disappear when the top menu exceeded the height of the screen. I'll try and update my question later on with the code when I have time. :)

Comment: Sure thing. You can also wrap the inner contents of the push menu and move all the flex properties onto it. That way, the `push-menu` is fixed and its inner contents overflow when needed. Do take a look. https://jsfiddle.net/setgb8jc/